# Finding the best monotonic curve fit

Tags: matlab

Edit: Some time after I asked this question, an R package called `MonoPoly` (available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonoPoly/index.html)) came out that does exactly what I want. I highly recommend it.

---

I have a set of points I want to fit a curve to. The curve must be monotonic (never decreasing in value) i.e. the curve can only go upward or stay flat.

I originally had been polyfitting my results and this had been working great until I found a particular dataset. The polyfit for data in this dataset was non-monotonic.

I did some research and found a possible solution in [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/260827) post:

> Use lsqlin. Constrain the first derivative to be non-negative at both
>   ends of the domain of interest.

I'm coming from a programming rather than math background so this is a little beyond me. I don't know how to constrain the first derivative to be non-negative as he said. Also, I think in my case I need a curve so I should use [lsqcurvefit](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) but I don't know how to constrain it to produce monotonic curves.

Further research turned up [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/72931) post recommending `lsqcurvefit` but I can't figure out how to use the important part:

> Try this non-linear function F(x) also. You use it together with
>   lsqcurvefit but it require a start guess on the parameters. But it is
>   a nice analytic expression to give as a semi-empirical formula in a
>   paper or a report.
>
> %Monotone function F(x), with c0,c1,c2,c3 varitional constants F(x)=
>   c3 + exp(c0 - c1^2/(4*c2))*sqrt(pi)*...
>         Erfi((c1 + 2*c2*x)/(2*sqrt(c2))))/(2*sqrt(c2))
>
> %Erfi(x)=erf(i*x) (look mathematica) but the function %looks much like
>   x^3    %derivative f(x), probability density f(x)>=0
>   f(x)=dF/dx=exp(c0+c1*x+c2*x.^2)

I must have a monotonic curve but I'm not sure how to do it, even with all of this information. Would a random number be enough for a "start guess". Is `lsqcurvefit` best? How can I use it to produce a best fitting monotonic curve?

Thanks

Comment: How do you measure goodness? What is a "best fitting" model? Based on your question I assume you are looking for minimal least square error; is this assumption correct? You also have to assume some mathematical structure/function, you mention `polyfit`, what is the assumed degree?

Comment: Sorry. Least square error is right. 3 degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `lsqlin`. The derivative constrain is enforced in each data point, this could be easily modified if needed.

Two coefficient matrices are needed, one (`C`) for least square error calculation and one (`A`) for derivatives in the data points.

```
% Following lsqlin's notations

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PRE-PROCESSING
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% for reproducibility
rng(125)
degree  = 3;
n_data  = 10;
% dummy data
x       = rand(n_data,1);
d       = rand(n_data,1) + linspace(0,1,n_data).';

% limit on derivative - in each data point
b       = zeros(n_data,1);

% coefficient matrix
C       = nan(n_data, degree+1);
% derivative coefficient matrix
A       = nan(n_data, degree);

% loop over polynomial terms
for ii  = 1:degree+1
    C(:,ii) = x.^(ii-1);
    A(:,ii) = (ii-1)*x.^(ii-2);
end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% FIT - LSQ
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Unconstrained
% p1 = pinv(C)*y
p1 = fliplr((C\d).')

p2 = polyfit(x,d,degree)

% Constrained
p3 = fliplr(lsqlin(C,d,-A,b).')

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PLOT
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
xx = linspace(0,1,100);

plot(x, d, 'x')
hold on
plot(xx, polyval(p1, xx))
plot(xx, polyval(p2, xx),'--')
plot(xx, polyval(p3, xx))

legend('data', 'lsq-pseudo-inv', 'lsq-polyfit', 'lsq-constrained', 'Location', 'southoutside')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
```

For the specified input the fitted curves:
[image]

Actually this code is more general than what you requested, since the degree of polynomial can be changed as well.

**EDIT: enforce derivative constrain in additional points**

The issue pointed out in the comments is due to that the derivative checks are enforced only in the data points. Between those no checks are performed. Below is a solution to alleviate this problem. The idea: convert the problem to an unconstrained optimization by using a penalty term.

Note that it is using a term `pen` to penalize the violation of the derivative check, thus the result is not a true least square error solution. Additionally, the result is dependent on the penalty function.

```
function lsqfit_constr
% Following lsqlin's notations

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PRE-PROCESSING
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% for reproducibility
rng(125)
degree  = 3;

% data from comment
x       = [0.2096 -3.5761 -0.6252 -3.7951 -3.3525 -3.7001 -3.7086 -3.5907].';
d       = [95.7750 94.9917 90.8417 62.6917 95.4250 89.2417 89.4333 82.0250].';
n_data  = length(d);

% number of equally spaced points to enforce the derivative
n_deriv = 20;
xd      = linspace(min(x), max(x), n_deriv);

% limit on derivative - in each data point
b       = zeros(n_deriv,1);

% coefficient matrix
C       = nan(n_data, degree+1);
% derivative coefficient matrix
A       = nan(n_deriv, degree);

% loop over polynom terms
for ii  = 1:degree+1
    C(:,ii) = x.^(ii-1);
    A(:,ii) = (ii-1)*xd.^(ii-2);
end

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% FIT - LSQ
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Unconstrained
% p1 = pinv(C)*y
p1      = (C\d);
lsqe    = sum((C*p1 - d).^2);

p2      = polyfit(x,d,degree);

% Constrained
[p3, fval] = fminunc(@error_fun, p1);

% correct format for polyval
p1      = fliplr(p1.')
p2
p3      = fliplr(p3.')
fval

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PLOT
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
xx      = linspace(-4,1,100);

plot(x, d, 'x')
hold on
plot(xx, polyval(p1, xx))
plot(xx, polyval(p2, xx),'--')
plot(xx, polyval(p3, xx))

% legend('data', 'lsq-pseudo-inv', 'lsq-polyfit', 'lsq-constrained', 'Location', 'southoutside')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% NESTED FUNCTION
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function e = error_fun(p)
        % squared error 
        sqe = sum((C*p - d).^2);
        der = A*p;

        % penalty term - it is crucial to fine tune it
        pen = -sum(der(der<0))*10*lsqe;

        e   = sqe + pen;
    end
end
```

[image]

Gradient free methods might be used to solve the problem by exactly enforcing the derivative constrain, for example:

```
[p3, fval] = fminsearch(@error_fun, p_ini);

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% NESTED FUNCTION
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function e = error_fun(p)
    % squared error
    sqe = sum((C*p - d).^2);
    der = A*p;

    if any(der<0)
        pen = Inf;
    else
        pen = 0;
    end

    e   = sqe + pen;
end
```

`fmincon` with non-linear constraint might be a better choice.
I let you to work out the details and to tune the algorithms. I hope that it is sufficient.

Comment: The code worked for nearly every situation but produced a non-monotonic curve when the x = [0.2096   -3.5761   -0.6252   -3.7951   -3.3525   -3.7001   -3.7086   -3.5907] and y = [95.7750   94.9917   90.8417   62.6917   95.4250   89.2417   89.4333   82.0250]. Is it that this can't be done with negative numbers? Here's a screenshot of the graph: http://imgur.com/lyP8yO9

Comment: This is MORE than sufficient! Thank you! What is the name of this method? Penalized derivative fit? Is there an official term?

Comment: @PhloxMidas I am pretty sure that the algorithm I put together is too specific to have its own name. Using a penalty term to convert an unconstrained optimization problem to a constrained one is called [penalty method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method).

Comment: @PhloxMidas "produced a non-monotonic curve when the x = [0.2096 -3.5761 -0.6252 -3.7951 [...]" – Are you sure that isn't just because your data is not ordered by x value?